# How to refresh Magento product list every 10sec

Tags: list, magento, product

I am trying to refresh product list every 10sec in magento.

```
<script>
function AutoRefresh(){
    var xmlHttp;
    try{
      xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    }
    catch (e){
      try{
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
      }
      catch (e){
        try{
          xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e){
          alert("No AJAX");
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

      if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        document.getElementById('products-grid').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        setTimeout('AutoRefresh()',10000); // JavaScript function calls AutoRefresh() every 3 seconds
      }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET","<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)?>list-response.php",true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
  }

  AutoRefresh();

</script>
```

but how to post values to particular page 
i mean i am sending to this page

```
xmlHttp.open("GET","<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)?>list-response.php",true);
```

but it is not correct. anybody tell me how to refresh product list page every 10sec using magento.

Thanks

Comment: What on earth could the purpose of this be?

Comment: If you can explain your goal I may be able to suggest something, I can't really see what you are trying to do here

Comment: @benmarks: maybe someone trying to use Magento as auctioning system^^

Comment: actually i am trying to do change product prices every 1min. this is online jewellery website. these product prices will come from third party xml feed. so i am over riding product price from array of product when page loading. third party product prices  may be or may not change every minute. for that i am refreshing div of product grid every one minute.

Comment: for example gold price depends upon stock market.these price will com from 3rd party xml. 1gr=10pounds..... now my product weight is 10gr then i have to change product price 100pounds in my website. i want to apply this prices to tier prices also.and prices will update every minute